# Localization & Warning: Multiple build commands

Tags: ios, ios5, localization

I would like to localize my apps with same filename. The very first thing is to localize Splash screen. The file & folder structure is like this:

MyApp/
  en.lproj/
    Default.png
    Default@2x.png
  zh-Hant.lproj/
    Default.png
    Default@2x.png

Then, I drag the 4 `Default.png` to xCode, making the xCode look like this:

[image: Multiple Default.png]

Warnings occurred for each `Default.png`, saying that `Warning: Multiple build commands`. Did I miss something? Or did I do something extra?

**UPDATE**: the localization works (except there are warnings). Can I do the same for all images? As I have 300+ images for my apps, I don't want to make it wrong at this stage. Just to make sure I am in right track, but the Warning makes me so uncomfortable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Build Phases of the Target you are building. Then expand Copy Bundle Resources as in the image below.[image: Sample]

You should see the file raising the warning in this list twice. Also, if you have any .git references in there you can remove them. Xcode is complaining because you are attempting to bundle one file multiple times in your project. Delete the offending reference and rebuild, it should now be error free.

Comment: correct. when adding launch images in different languages, xCode duplicated the files in `Copy Bundle Resources` phase.